# Is it possible to compile Xamarin for Android from Linux CLI?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

We have an Android app that is compiled with custom information according to each client. 
At the moment, our app is built using Ionic, so when a user asks to download the APK, we automatically modify its source code accordingly, compile the app and provide the download from the client.
All of this is done in a Linux server.

We now want to leave Ionic and use Xamarin for our new version. But we need to achieve the same process that we had before.
So is it possible to compile Xamarin for Android from Linux just like we do `ionic build android`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer : Yes, but....

Linux not a currently supported environment by the **distributed pre-packaged** version of `Xamarin.Android` from Microsoft/Xamarin, but using the open-sourced code, you can build `Xamarin.Android` on *Linux* and then  use `xabuild` on your `Xamarin.Android` projects.

Note: You are on your own in terms of setup, environment, bugs, etc... (but the open source code is being built on an Ubuntu build server, see the Github repo for details)

**Github repo**: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android

Ref: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=142

New Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/Documentation/workflow/UsingYourBuild.md

Old Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android#linux-build-notes

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, though it will be much easier once .net 5 appears.

Use this docker image (directly or for inspiration): https://hub.docker.com/r/vonproteus/xamarin-android-docker

And then run `msbuild SolutionFile.sln /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/android/sdk /restore`

Answer (score 0):

I tried https://hub.docker.com/r/vonproteus/xamarin-android-docker in Linux Mint machine.

```
docker pull vonproteus/xamarin-android-docker
```

then

```
sudo docker run -v ~/Downloads/Helloworld/:/test vonproteus/xamarin-android-docker msbuild test/Helloworld.Android/Helloworld.Android.csproj /restore /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/android/sdk /p:AndroidBuildApplicationPackage=true
```

Just change `~/Downloads/Helloworld/` and `Helloworld.Android/Helloworld.Android.csproj` to your project location and Android project name.

`-v ~/Downloads/Helloworld/:/test` means that we are creating a virtual directory inside docker so that msbuild can work. `msbuild` would throw `MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.` if you don't set the virtual path.