# Getting dotnet sdk not found error when running MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, mono

I'm getting dotnet sdk not found error when running MSBuild. How to resolve this?

`$ dotnet msbuild . 
/home/deshpand/angebotsapp/kommmit.Offers/kommmit.Offers.Android/kommmit.Offers.Android.csproj(393,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/Novell/Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

Comment: Do not use `dotnet` as that is a Xamarin.Android project, directly use MSBuild

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54735479/how-to-install-msbuild-on-centos/54740878?noredirect=1#comment96426767_54740878 . I had to install msbuild using dotnet libraries, So i can run msbuild only using "dotnet msbuild" or "dotnet ." . Can you please provide solution for the same. The solution for running android project using dotnet msbuild or how should i install stand alone msbuild on CentOS.

Comment: 1) You can get msbuild via a current Mono distro. 2) You would need Mono to build an Xamarin.Android project on macOS/Linux, 3) Xamarin.Android is not officially supported (via a pre-compiled installer) on Linux (only MacOS/Windows), you would need to build Xamarin.Android specifically for your Linus distro, see the  following that has links to the GitHub repo : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129613/is-it-possible-to-compile-xamarin-for-android-from-linux-cli/39129702#39129702